# PythonでChromeを立ち上げる時に｢attributeerror partially initialized module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'chrome'｣と表示されます。

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

今までだと起動出来ていたのですが、2、3日前から起動しなくなり、｢attributeerror partially initialized module'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'chrome'｣と出てきました。
フォルダ名は｢ああ｣、ファイル名は｢立ち上げ.py｣になります。
Mac OS
python3.9.7
chrome103.0.5060.53
chromedriver103.0.5060.53
になります。
seleniumもインストールしています。
コードは下のようになります。

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = './chromedriver' 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

time.sleep (3)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: selenium, chromeブラウザ, chromedriver のどれかが更新されて版数が合わなくなったとかありませんか？ [webdriver-manager - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) とか使うと自動的にchromedriverを合わせてくれるようですが。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。版数は確認したところ一致しておりました。webdriver-managerの方もダウンロードし使ってみましたが全く同じエラーメッセージが出てきて何も起動しません。

Comment: 何かが問題になっているはずなので、Python自身やOS・開発・動作環境等も含めて具体的な名前や版数の情報を詳細に記述した方が助言や回答が出やすいでしょう。

Comment: 教えて頂きありがとうございます。ご意見を頂いた通りに編集し記載させて頂きました。

Answer (score 0):

コード上でもサービスをインストールできるはずです。

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

これで自動的にインストールしてみるのはどうですか。